# Changing multi divs style by same event with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

As you see in code there are four divs and every div has a button inside to change its parent elements style (background color).
How can I change background color property of all divs except clicked ones parent by the same event ?

```js
function getId(btnId, prnId) {
  var buttonId = btnId;
  var btnValue = document.getElementById(buttonId).value;
  var parentId = prnId;
  document.getElementById(parentId).style.backgroundColor = btnValue;
  var frameColor = document.getElementById('main');
  frameColor.style.backgroundColor = btnValue;
  var clearOthers = document.getElementsByClassName('colorBox');
  for (i=0;i<clearOthers.length;i++){
    if(clearOthers[i].firstElementChild.innerHTML!=btnValue){
      clearOthers[i].style.backgroundColor="white";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
    <div id="redBox" class="colorBox">
        <button id="redBtn" value="red" class="changeColor" onClick="getId(this.id,this.parentNode.id)">RED</button>
    </div>
    <div id="blueBox" class="colorBox">
        <button id="blueBtn" value="blue" class="changeColor" onClick="getId(this.id,this.parentNode.id)">BLUE</button>
    </div>
    <div id="yellowBox" class="colorBox">
        <button id="yellowBtn" value="yellow" class="changeColor" onClick="getId(this.id,this.parentNode.id)">YELLOW</button>
    </div>
    <div id="blackBox" class="colorBox">
        <button id="blackBtn" value="black" class="changeColor" onCLick="getId(this.id,this.parentNode.id)">BLACK</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost done .Change the `value` instead of `innerHTML` on matching if condition

```js
function getId(btnId, prnId) {
  var buttonId = btnId;
  var btnValue = document.getElementById(buttonId).value;
  var parentId = prnId;
  document.getElementById(parentId).style.backgroundColor = btnValue;
  var frameColor = document.getElementById('main');
  frameColor.style.backgroundColor = btnValue;
  var clearOthers = document.getElementsByClassName('colorBox');
  for (i = 0; i < clearOthers.length; i++) {
    if (clearOthers[i].firstElementChild.value != btnValue) {
      clearOthers[i].style.backgroundColor = "white";
    }
  }

}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="redBox" class="colorBox">
    <button id="redBtn" value="red" class="changeColor" onClick="getId(this.id,this.parentNode.id)">RED</button>
  </div>
  <div id="blueBox" class="colorBox">
    <button id="blueBtn" value="blue" class="changeColor" onClick="getId(this.id,this.parentNode.id)">BLUE</button>
  </div>
  <div id="yellowBox" class="colorBox">
    <button id="yellowBtn" value="yellow" class="changeColor" onClick="getId(this.id,this.parentNode.id)">YELLOW</button>
  </div>
  <div id="blackBox" class="colorBox">
    <button id="blackBtn" value="black" class="changeColor" onCLick="getId(this.id,this.parentNode.id)">BLACK</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are doing it right but you are clearing the color after assigning it, Do it before assigning the new color.

```js
function getId(btnId, prnId) {
  var clearOthers = document.getElementsByClassName('colorBox');
  for (var i = 0; i < clearOthers.length; i++) {
    clearOthers[i].style.backgroundColor = "white";
  }
  var buttonId = btnId;
  var btnValue = document.getElementById(buttonId).value;
  var parentId = prnId;
  document.getElementById(parentId).style.backgroundColor = btnValue;
  var frameColor = document.getElementById('main');
  frameColor.style.backgroundColor = btnValue;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="redBox" class="colorBox">
    <button id="redBtn" value="red" class="changeColor" onClick="getId(this.id,this.parentNode.id)">RED</button>
  </div>
  <div id="blueBox" class="colorBox">
    <button id="blueBtn" value="blue" class="changeColor" onClick="getId(this.id,this.parentNode.id)">BLUE</button>
  </div>
  <div id="yellowBox" class="colorBox">
    <button id="yellowBtn" value="yellow" class="changeColor" onClick="getId(this.id,this.parentNode.id)">YELLOW</button>
  </div>
  <div id="blackBox" class="colorBox">
    <button id="blackBtn" value="black" class="changeColor" onCLick="getId(this.id,this.parentNode.id)">BLACK</button>
  </div>
</div>
```